# Create view with scalar column

Tags: sql, oracle

Can I create an Oracle view like this statement?

```
create or replace view FARMERS_DATA
AS
SELECT DISTINCT F.FNAME
       , F.LNAME
       , F.REGION
       , P.NAME
       , SP.NAME as SUB_PRODUCT_NAME
       , number(2) as PRICE
FROM FARMERS F, PRODUCT P, SUB_PRODUCT SP
WHERE SP.PRODUCT_ID = P.PRODUCTID
ORDER BY F.FNAME
```

I want that the last column will be a scalar - not a data from another table.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by `number(2) as Price`. Do you want to show constant value `2` as `price`

Comment: I want to upadte view with diffrenet prices in each row, price is 2 digits integer.

Comment: You cannot update a view. You can update the underlying table.

Comment: I know, but i want only update the column of the integer that not connected to any table. is it possible?

Comment: @ShayZambrovski When you say update do you mean `UPDATE` a table, or are you talking about just using some sort of row counter?  Would `ROWNUM` work?

Comment: Maybe you could create a "support" table, with only one field and one row, and use that to store your varying value?

Comment: Unrelated, but: you are missing a join between farmers and product. Another good example why one should not use the old out-dated implicit joins in the where clause and start using an explicit JOIN operator

Answer (score 1):

You want a view with an empty column which has a numeric datatype.  You can do that with a CAST() like this:

```
create or replace view FARMERS_DATA
AS
SELECT DISTINCT F.FNAME
       , F.LNAME
       , F.REGION
       , P.NAME
       , SP.NAME as SUB_PRODUCT_NAME
       , cast(null as number(2)) as PRICE
FROM FARMERS F, PRODUCT P, SUB_PRODUCT SP
WHERE SP.PRODUCT_ID = P.PRODUCTID
ORDER BY F.FNAME
```